# Coded UI test stalls without stopping when same function is called repetitively

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have a test which calls a function multiple times. It works fine initially without any slowdown. However after running multiple times, it slows down and then just stalls and doesn't even fail. I have to manually stop the execution.

I have used AlwaysSearch for this function as I don't want it retrieve information from cached data. However, that still doesn't work.

```
            xyx.function1.GoToNextSaturday();
            xyz.function1.GoToNextWeek();
            xyz.function1.GoToNextWeek();
            xyz.function1.GoToNextWeek();
            xyz.function1.GoToNextWeek();

            abc.function2(0);


            var x = abc.func3();

            abc.func4()
            Playback.Wait(3000);

            abc.fun5()

            xyz.function1.GoToNextWeek();
            xyz.function1.GoToNextWeek();
            xyz.function1.GoToNextWeek();
```

Comment: Might be running low on memory and doing lots of garbage collections. Please [edit] the question to add much more detail of the test code.

Comment: UITestControl.Find() does the same thing in a explicit way. Does your test still slow down to a stall if you disable AlwaysSearch and use .Find() instead?